# Complexity of the algorithm that represnts the expression (n*(n-1)/2)

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

For the equation : `(n(n-1))/2`

If you were to write an algorithm to represent this equation, what would be the complexity of such an algorithm?

Comment: Are you asking about the complexity of an algorithm to compute `n*(n-1)/2` for a given n, or are you asking about the complexity of an algorithm that requires `n*(n-1)/2` steps to complete?

Answer (score 3):

Time complexity of `(n*(n-1))/2` will be `O(n^2)`.

This expression `1+2+3+4+...n-1` can be evaluated with `O(n)`  algorithm. And the time complexity of "resulting formula" need not always be the same(or linear). Big O notation can not be applied like that.

if a function is represented as `(n*(n-1))/2` , it's rate of growth will not be linear. And Big O notation will talk about rate of growth of a function, so, the time complexity of `(n*(n-1))/2` is `O(n^2)`

To be more specific, while calculating `(n*(n-1))` for a larger value of n,  you have to store each and every digit of number in an array and after that multiply them. This will take `O(N^2)` time complexity where N is the number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

`(n*(n-1))/2`  can be represented as `(1 + 2 + ... + (n-1))`. Finding the sum using this expanded expression would have `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

If you don't expand `(n*(n-1))/2` into sum-expression, then it takes `O(1)` time complexity to do `(n*(n-1))/2`.

Why `O(n)` for expanded(sum) expression?

Since you are going to do the addition by considering `(n-1)` elements one by one. 
So `O(n)` is considered same as `O(n-1)`.

Comment: This is only true for small `n` - if `n` doesn't fit into one (32/64 bit) register, you cannot assume that an addition or multiplication requires only `O(1)` time.